# Sort nested list based on numerical part of a string element

Tags: python, sorting

I have:

```
l = [['T182', 'XXX-0'], ['S41', 'Q8BFU2-0']]
```

I want:

```
[['S41', 'Q8BFU2-0'], ['T182', 'XXX-0']]
```

My current solution is to build a new nested list:

```
i = [['T', '182', 'XXX-0'], ['S', '41', 'Q8BFU2-0']]
```

Which allows me to easily obtain my result, although not using an optimal way.

What I want from `l` is to apply a numerical sort on this nested list based on the numerical part of the first element of each sublist.

This without reconstructing the nested list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the elements follow the pattern one character plus an integer you could do this:

```
res = sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x[0][1:]))
```

`x[0]` selects the first elements of your sublists; `x[0][1:]` selects everything but the first character. what remains will be converted to an integer and used as `key` for `sorted`.